# backspace undoes and enter redoes

Tags: ms-word

Sorry if this isnt the right place for this question but Im in a hurry and dont know where else to get an answer quickly.

I was typing a regular document in word and somehow, seemingly randomly, the controls changed. Now when I highlight or click text, word automatically "Researches" it on a side bar that pops up. Also when I hit the backspace button, it performs the Undo function. When i hit enter, it performs the redo. 
for example, If i type a string, say, "hello world", then if i hit enter three times, the result would be "hello worldhello worldhello worldhello world" and then pressing backspace would delete all four hello worlds at once. I dont know if theres something I accidentally clicked, but I cant find help online anywhere for this weird specific problem. If anyone knows what's going on and how I can change it back without saving/restarting word every time it happens, please help me lol. Thanks!

edit: Im running windows 8 on a dell inpiron 15 7548 and microsoft office 2013

Comment: It sounds as if it COULD be an add-in or a macro virus. If a normal re-start, such as suggested in the "answer" doesn't help: Try starting Word in SAFE mode (hold down CTRL when starting it) and see if the problem corrects itself. If it does, then it's something that's installed and loading when Word starts. You'll find plenty of instructions on the Internet on how to track down the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any settings or keystrokes in Word to enable that behavior (at least with the Backspace/Enter buttons). It may be an issue with your keyboard, if you are using a multimedia/customizable or laptop keyboard.

If restarting Word corrects the issue, then that is the easiest temporary solution. You can also try to completely reinstall Office if you don't think they keyboard is the issue.

Overall, you should contact Microsoft to see if they can help. If they can't find the issue, then it's most likely an issue with your machine.